# How to Run Excel macro from SharePoint?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a document library in SharePoint.

I export to Excel and then run a macro stored in my personal workbook to manipulate the data.

Can the macro be stored in SharePoint and run against Excel from there?

Answer (score 1):

When navigating to the file in Sharepoint, it's simple to open the file directly in Excel with live editing to Sharepoint, if you enable high frequency Autosave parameters in Excel (or globally across Office).

This will enable your in-document Macros to operate.

If your macros are stored external to the document itself, you may need to map these connections inside of Excel in the "Data" tab on the ribbon, then select "Connections" and select "Add", which will give you the Fie Explorer dialogue for you to choose where the connections (which can include macros, other Excel files, SQL databases etc) are to be maintained, and also allows you to refresh these as the source may be updated or moved. This can be in Sharepoint. Please make sure your permissions are correctly set for this.

The Office browser versions (i.e. Microsoft Word/Excel/PowerPoint Web App) don't support Macros (at least not as of or up to Office 2013).